# How can I add/deduct a column of integer in Business Days to a column of datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

My dataframe is sth like below:

| ID | Days of Holiday | First Day of Holiday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 3 | 16/03/2021 |
| B01 | 10 | 24/03/2021 |
| C02 | 3 | 31/03/2021 |
| D03 | 2 | 02/04/2021 |

I am trying to figure out a way to create another column "First Day of Return from holiday".

I tried to loop through DF using iterrow like below (DF above is "Calendar"):

```
for i, r in Calendar.iterrows():\
    Calendar["First Day of Return from holiday"] = Calendar["First Day of Holiday"] + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(n = r["Days of Holiday"])
```

And I don't get a correct output with above.

Any other way can you recommend me?

Basically, looking for ways to add/deduct integer column to a datetime column of the same row in business days.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does the `Days of Holiday` column include weekends or just working days?

Comment: I have modified the code for the logic of Business Days, you can check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda function :

```
df['First Day of Return from holiday'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.['First Day of Holiday'] + row.['Days of Holiday'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First we convert the First Day of Holiday Date to `datetime` datatype and Number of Holidays to `int` datatype, then we initiate the new column by zeros. We can iterate and assign the value to each row of new column using BDay function to get Business Days. Then we can convert the dates back to the date format we require.

However, the date will be converted to a standard format which can be converted back to the format required using `.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df['First Day of Holiday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Day of Holiday'])
df['Days of Holiday'] = df['Days of Holiday'].astype('int')
df['First Day of Return from holiday'] = [0]*len(df.index)
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'First Day of Return from holiday'] = r['First Day of Holiday'] + BDay(n=r['Days of Holiday'])
df['First Day of Holiday'] = df['First Day of Holiday'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['First Day of Return from holiday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Day of Return from holiday'])
df['First Day of Return from holiday'] = df['First Day of Return from holiday'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This totally works! Thank you. Would you have another suggestion for business holidays? Currently, "First Day of Return from holiday" only excludes weekends I believe. However in other countries, say in Korea, I have a list of business holidays that need to be excluded from deriving the First Day of Return from holiday.

Comment: @VbC you should check CustomBusinessDay function of pandas, here is the reference documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html

Comment: @VbC Here they show how to create a customized holiday calender https://towardsdatascience.com/holiday-calendars-with-pandas-9c01f1ee5fee

Comment: @VbC Would you consider validating this answer as correct, if it solved your issue?